# How can I declare a variable to be an empty object before I add functions to it in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert my javascript to Typescript and came up with another problem. Here's the code I have:

```
var util = {};
```

Then later in the code:

```
util.extendRegExp = function (regex, pre, post) {

    if (pre === null || pre === undefined) {
        pre = "";
    }
    if (post === null || post === undefined) {
        post = "";
    }
```

I tried to declare an interface like this:

```
interface Iutil = { extendRegExp (any) }

...
...
var util: Iutil = {};
```

but now I am getting an error message saying:

```
Can't convert {} to Iutil. util is missing the property extendRegExp
```

Is there a way I can do the `var util = {}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assert the empty object as your interface type when you assign it:

```
   var util: Iutil = {} as Iutil;
```

Then you can assign the function later.

If TypeScript still complains (e.g. no overlap between type or something like that) then you can do an assertion to `any` and then to your interface:

```
   var util: Iutil = {} as any as Iutil;
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (I prefer) is to mark it as `optional` using `?` because to be honest it is something that may or may not exist as soon as you start using type assertions:

```
interface Iutil { extendRegExp? (any) }
var util: Iutil = {}; // No error
```